# How does Transport layer retrieve the source IP address from a datagram packet?

Tags: protocols

How does Transport layer retrieve the source IP address from a datagram packet?
From what I understand the IPaddress is in the network layer header and the Transport layer header only contains the source port and destination port.Please let me know if I am missing something

Comment: I'm guessing that you wonder how calls like `recvfrom` fills in the source address? I suggest reading the source to Linux, BSD or any other operating system with an open network stack, as this is highly OS dependent.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is the Transport layer does not retrieve the IP address from the datagram packet.

When a datagram is sent from the source to the destination, here are simple steps on how IP works with when a datagram travels:

- Upper-layer application sends a packet to the Network Layer.
- Data calculation alongwith the checksum.
- IP header and datagram constructed.
- Routed through gateways.
- Each gateway's IP layer performs checksum. If checksum does not match,
  the datagram will be dropped and an error message will send back to
  the sending machine. Along the way, if TTL decrements to 0, the same
  result will occur. And, the destination address routing path will be
  determined on every stop as the datagram passes along the
  network.
- Datagram gets to the Network Layer of destination.
- Checksum calculation performed.
- IP header taken out.
- Message passes to upper-layer application.

**EDIT**

An application binds a socket to its endpoint of data transmission, which is a combination of an IP address and a service port. This binding is then used to determine which application at the application layer this needs to go to.

For example Application A is providing a UDP service on a certain port X. Then when Application A starts it will try and bind to port X. If it is unable to bind to it because the port is in use, the operating system will raise an error which the application then must handle. Also in the OSI architecture each layer relies on the layer below it for the actual transmission of data, adding or providing specific functionality for its own intended purpose.

According to the RFC

> The pseudo  header  conceptually prefixed to the UDP header contains the
> source  address,  the destination  address,  the protocol,  and the  UDP
> length.   This information gives protection against misrouted datagrams.
> This checksum procedure is the same as is used in TCP.

For more details about the specifics please check out the RFC [User Datagram Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768)

Comment: This didn't answer the question. He's asking how the upper layers, like the Transport Layer (or even the Application Layer) determine the IP address since they obviously don't have access to the IP header.

Comment: His question is, since the upper layers obviously know the IP address it's clear they're getting it from somewhere. How are they getting it?

Comment: @JonathanM I have added some more clarification and a link to the RFC.